# How to create an entity handler that accepts arguments?

Tags: 8, entities

I've created a module and entity using [Drupal Console](https://github.com/hechoendrupal/DrupalConsole/).  It defines a canonical route like this:

```
entity.score.canonical:
  path: '/admin/score/{score}'
  defaults:
    # Calls the view controller, defined in the annotation of the score entity
    _entity_view: 'score'
    _title: 'Score'
  requirements:
    _entity_access: 'score.view'
  options:
    _admin_route: TRUE
```

I want to create a similar route that calls a handler which will render an entity by referencing a field value other than the entity id.

How is that done?

Comment: This will be nice if is been supported by DrupalConsole. I ping jmoliva (DrupalConsole, maintainer) about it and he likes the idea on later in the future support this.  I have open an issue about this - https://github.com/hechoendrupal/DrupalConsole/issues/1657